# bundle.getString returns a null string

Tags: android, arguments, bundle

I can't understand where I'm wrong in passing arguments from an activity to a fragment.

In the `MyActivity.class`

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", "helloworld");
HomeFragment homefragment = new HomeFragment();
homefragment.setArguments(bundle); 
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, homefragment).commit();
```

And in my fragment I try to take the arguments this way inside the onCreateView method but the string is always null

`onCreateView()`

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if(bundle != null)
        mName = bundle.getString("name"); //mName here is null, checked with a simple print

//this is for the viewpager
models = new ArrayList<>();
    Resources res = getResources();
    mDescriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.newGameDescription);
    mTitle = res.getStringArray(R.array.newGame);
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.brochure,mTitle[0], mDescriptions[0]));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.sticker,mTitle[1], mDescriptions[1]));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.poster,mTitle[2], mDescriptions[2]));
    models.add(new Model(R.drawable.namecard,mTitle[3], mDescriptions[3]));

    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getContext(), models, mName); // I pass the string value here to pass it to an activity (with putextra) after clicking on a page of the viewer

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.gameModeViewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setPadding(130,0,130,0);

    Integer[] colors_temp = {
            getResources().getColor(R.color.prova1),
            getResources().getColor(R.color.prova2),
            getResources().getColor(R.color.prova3),
            getResources().getColor(R.color.prova4),
    };

    colors = colors_temp;
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {
            if (i < (adapter.getCount() - 1) && i < (colors.length -1)){
                viewPager.setBackgroundColor((Integer)argbEvaluator.evaluate(v, colors[i], colors[i+1]));
            }else{
                viewPager.setBackgroundColor(colors[colors.length -1]);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });


    return view;
```

Code added after being asked in the comments, I do not manipulate the string in any way

Comment: is it really a problem seems you are doing it right anyways share more of code to troubleshoot - share your onCreateView

Comment: my fragment only implements a viewpager, I do not manipulate the string in any way @vikassharma

Comment: code added to the post @vikassharma

Comment: still not getting the error, is your bundle null or bundle argument "name" return null?

Comment: bundle argument "name" return null @vikassharma

Comment: give this a try  `public static HomeFragment newInstance(int index) {
    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("name", "helloworld");
    homeFragment.setArguments(args);
    return homeFragment;
}`

Comment: @vikassharma this does not work. The fragment however with the code I wrote is loaded and displayed well, the only thing that does not work is the string in the bundle

Answer (score 0):

From your activity

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("name", "123456789");
FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA ();
fragmentA .setArguments(b);

fm.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentA())
.commit();
```

And this in the fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String text = getArguments().getString("name");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: in this way I get a NullPointerException. I did this before separating the getArguments() and getString() methods

Comment: what tabId stands for?

Comment: @james Check the edited answer, but I am looking now at your code and find a way to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
```

Use this

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
```